# chalice package: Could not install dependencies: graphqlclient==0.2.4

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, chalice

While running `chalice package` command I am getting this error:

```
$ chalice package --stage preview .chalice/deployments/preview
Creating deployment package.

Could not install dependencies:
graphqlclient==0.2.4
You will have to build these yourself and vendor them in
the chalice vendor folder.

Your deployment will continue but may not work correctly
if missing dependencies are not present. For more information:
http://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/packaging.html
```

I am using macbook pro. Other team mates are also using same machine but they are not getting this error. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running command with sudo fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have pip installed everything:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Next if you still have the error you need to get the wheel of the package and put it in a folder called 'vendor' and put it in your chalice root directory.

```
- .chalice
- chalicelib
  - helloworld.py
- vendor
  - graphqlclient-any.whl
- app.py
- requirements.txt
```